# Ubuntu thinkpad e15 gen2 lid and fn keys not working

Tags: 20.04, suspend, thinkpad, function-keys, lid

I just got the thinkpad e15 gen2 (amd) and I installed ubuntu 20.04 lts on it and I can't seem to be able to get the fn keys working nor can I get the laptop to suspend when closing the lid. For the lid there are no options in the power settings and editing the logind.config file does not work either. the lid status in terminal does work correctly.

I can't get the FN keys to work. I tried to change the bios settings, but disabling, swapping or putting the fn as default or not are not working. Testing for key output in terminal did work for the keys when they were in f1, f2,.. but I don't get any output when they are in fn mode. (pressing fn key gave wakeup command?) I know linux a bit for programming, however I am a bit out of my league here and I do not know how to proceed. Could you help me or point me in the right direction?

Comment: This issue is already adressed in this thread:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/602355/thinkpad-fn-keys-only-working-after-suspend

and the Lenovo forum:

https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Other-Linux-Discussions/Linux-Fn-keys-not-working-Thinkpad-E14-AMD-Gen-2/m-p/5027791?page=3

However the function keys do work as expected after suspending the laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit late maybe, but Lenovo confirmed this bug a few weeks ago and has released a new BIOS update yesterday that fixes this issue. I've installed it and it works fine now. You can download the update on [the official Lenovo website](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds544315-bios-update-utility-bootable-cd-for-windows-10-64-bit-thinkpad-e14-gen-2-thinkpad-e15-gen-2), it should work smoothly after that.
Note that this update is primarily rolled out for Windows, so you have to install the update via the provided ISO file. You can do this with a bootable USB, see [here](https://workaround.org/article/updating-the-bios-on-lenovo-laptops-from-linux-using-a-usb-flash-stick/) for an example.

Comment: I can't seem to get it to boot from a USB with the ISO. I've tried half a dozen methods to create the bootable USB.

Comment: So what exactly does not work? Are you able to write the ISO file on USB? Or hat is the problem? Please give me some more details.

Comment: I'm able to write the ISO file to the USB, but the computer will not boot from the USB. When selecting the USB from the boot menu, the screen flashes black then goes back to the boot menu. I eventually gave up and re-installed Windows 10, ran the exe to update the BIOS, then re-installed Ubuntu. It was even hard to get it to boot from a Windows USB. Seems it won't boot from an NTFS USB, only FAT.

Answer (score 3):

After suspend, all the fn buttons start working. It's not a solution but can help a little bit.